# Target specific column and row in multiple rows of SQL database from App Inventor

Tags: mysql, app-inventor

I have a database with over 1000 rows and 7 columns.

[image]

How would I target row 4 column 3 in App Inventor and sign that value to a variable?
I have looked everywhere to find a solution online for this problem in App Inventor but I continue to go in circles.

Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

Send a SELECT query to the MySQL database like this

```
SELECT image_url FROM <tablename> WHERE image_no = <your image number variable>
```

and of course `<your image number variable>` can be any number you like to select, for example 4...

As interface between App Inventor and your MySQL database you could use [this solution](https://puravidaapps.com/mysql.php), alternatively set up your own php script.

In App Inventor you will receive the result in the `Web.GotText` event.

A very good way to learn App Inventor is to read the free Inventor's Manual here in the AI2 free online eBook   http://www.appinventor.org/book2 ... the links are at the bottom of the Web page.  The book 'teaches' users how to program with AI2 blocks.
There is a free programming course here http://www.appinventor.org/content/CourseInABox/Intro  and the aia files for the projects in the book are here:  http://www.appinventor.org/bookFiles
How to do a lot of basic things with App Inventor are described here:  http://www.appinventor.org/content/howDoYou/eventHandling  .

Also do the tutorials http://appinventor.mit.edu/explore/ai2/tutorials.html to learn the basics of App Inventor, then try something and follow the
 [Top 5 Tips: How to learn  App Inventor](https://puravidaapps.com/learn.php)

Comment: I wish I could use this but as the app continues the imageno changes from 1 to 1000 so I need it to be a variable and not the actual number 4. Why is there so little functionality in the grabbing of information from SQL. A lot of documentation on insert and update but the internet lacks a lot on Select.

Comment: it seems to be, you still have to learn a lot... see my edited answer... and: do some tutorials to learn some basics, also feel free to Google for some SQL tutorials...